# How can I backup Gnome-shell extensions

Tags: installation, package-management, scripts, backup, extension

I'm creating my post-instalation script for my Ubuntu 12.04 LST x64 and I would like to know how can I backup current installed extensions. Can I create own extension package to easy install? Is here any way how can I install all my extensions with (only one) command over the terminal?

Thanks all for answers. I apologize for my bad english. I hope you will understand me a little.

Answer (score 0):

Your extensions should be installed in a directory in your home. Open your Home, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files, then navigate to `.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and make a backup of all the folders inside it.

Provided you will be using the same version of Gnome you're using now, you can simply copy all the backed-up folders in a new Home to have your extensions again.